# Implementing a functionality for processing heavy insertion

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I use PostgreSQL 9.1. The scenario is:

- I receive heavy insertion into `Table1` (about 100 rows per sec).
- For each new row, I have to check the previous and next row *of the source table* if those are inside an area using `ST_DWithin`.
- Join what I got with some data from `Table2`
- Insert/Update into `Table3`

Every new entry must go through this process. It's like I generate a new table from existing one.

`Table1`, which I select rows from

`Table2`, which I use it to join

`Table3`, where insert the new data

Currently I'm checking every row (because every row is a unique item) below is a part of it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_trigger()
    RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
    declare
        AnotifDate timestamp without time zone;
        lastmsg timestamp without time zone;
        InsideCircle integer;
        InsideSquare integer;
        insidePoint integer;
        distance character varying(40);
        inAction character varying(40);
        diff character varying(40);
        days character varying(40);
        hours character varying(40);
        str character varying(40);
        CinAction character varying(40);
        AinAction character varying(40);
    BEGIN 

    select time_stamp INTO Adate  from table1 where userid=NEW.userid and time_stamp < NEW.time_stamp order by time_stamp desc limit 1 ;
    select  position INTO Aposition from table1 where userid=NEW.userid and time_stamp < NEW.time_stamp order by time_stamp desc limit 1;
    select time_stamp INTO Cdate  from table1 where userid=NEW.userid and time_stamp > NEW.time_stamp order by time_stamp  limit 1; 
    select position INTO Cposition from table1 where userid=NEW.userid and time_stamp > NEW.time_stamp order by time_stamp  limit 1;

    SELECT p.num  INTO InsideCircle FROM table3 p WHERE ST_DWithin(Aposition,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326) ,0.02171302174) ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326),Aposition) limit 1;
    SELECT p.num  INTO InsideSquare FROM table3 p WHERE ST_DWithin(NEW.position ,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326) ,0.02171302174) ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326),NEW.position) limit 1;
    SELECT p.num  INTO insidePoint  FROM table3 p WHERE ST_DWithin(Cposition,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326) ,0.02171302174) ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(p.longitudedecimal,p.latitudedecimal ), 4326),Cposition) limit 1;


        IF (InsideCircle >0 and (InsideCircle =InsideSquare or InsideSquare is null))THEN 
        select startDate INTO startDate  from myTable where id=NEW.userid and num = InsideCircle and startDate =Adate; 
            IF (InsideSquare >0)then 
                if (Cdate is not null )then 
                    if (insidePoint is null)THEN 
                        diff = NEW.time_stamp  -startDate;
                        str= split_part(diff,' ',2);
                        IF(str = '')then
                        hours= split_part(diff,':',1);
                        days = '0';
                        ELSE
                        str= split_part(diff,' ',3);
                        IF(str = '') then
                        hours ='00';
                        days = split_part(diff,' ',1);
                        ELSE
                        hours= split_part( split_part(diff,' ',3),':',1);
                        days = split_part(diff,' ',1);
                        END IF;
                        END IF;
                        inAction = days || ',' ||hours;
                    Update myTable SET notifDate = NEW.time_stamp , time_inAction=inAction WHERE id=NEW.userid  and num =InsideSquare ;
                    END IF;

        END IF;
    Return Null;
    END;
```

#### Questions

- I used to use a trigger to do the checking and insertion/updating. Definition is as follows:

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER ts_trigger
>   AFTER INSERT
>   ON table1
>   FOR EACH ROW
>   EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_trigger();
> ```

But I don't think it's the efficient way to do it.

- I'm **interested** in using batches. I'd like to understand the technique but cannot find a good resource for it.

Somebody suggested a temp table, but I don't think it would be useful in my case.

Comment: Its unclear whether you want to check *within* patches, or every row against previous and next row (which is impossible on principal). Also unclear whether `new table` is a different table. And the elephant in the room: the question needs table definitions of involved tables and the trigger function (even if it's not working, yet). Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you need qualified assistance.

Comment: Aside: I have flagged the x-posted duplicate on SO for deletion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621431/implementing-a-functionality-for-processing-heavy-insertion#comment40042269_25621431

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Well, sorry for that, but I thought it'll be better to post in both here and there. I edited my post and added more details. I'd appreciated if you could take a look.

Comment: The function header of your trigger function is missing. It's an integral part, please complete it. The trigger definition is *not* the header (like you wrote, and I corrected). I also took the liberty to clarify a couple of things. Please check if I got that right. Also: is the current approach *working* as desired (except for performance)? You can probably do everything in a single query using window functions, but please complete the Q first.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I added the trigger to the post.and Thanks for the formatting edits! I haven't noticed anything wrong. about the approach, I haven't tested it yet. I've been questioning its efficiancy and that's why i opsted this question. Can you please explain the approach you mentioned? Many Thanks!